# How to adjust configuration Facebook sdk4 with Codeigniter?

Tags: php, facebook, .htaccess, codeigniter, facebook-graph-api

I set up Facebook sdk4 on my codeigniter files.
Here's all I've done.
- enroll my app as FB application
- implement FB sdk on library directory
- modify controller as below
- configure .htaccess as below
- Codeigniter ver 3.0RC3

My site is here.
https://dashboard.come-to.tokyo/

When I click on login, it redirects '404 Page Not Found'.
URL is like this.
https://dashboard.come-to.tokyo/?code=XXXX

controller.php

```
function index(){
    // UsreAgent
    $this->load->library('user_agent');

    // Common librualy
    $this->load->library('facebook');
    // grab facebook login url
    $this->login_url = $this->facebook->login_url();
    //$this->session = $this->facebook->get_session();

var_dump ($this->login_url);

// see if we have a session
if ( isset( $this->session ) ) {
  // graph api request for user data
  $request = new FacebookRequest( $session, 'GET', '/me' );
  $response = $request->execute();
  // get response
  $graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();

  // print data
  print_r( $graphObject, 1 );
} else {
  // show login url
  echo '<a href="' . $this->login_url . '">Login</a>';
}
```

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [L]
```

How should I do? I guess parameter like '?code=XXX' doesn't work properly.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In order for `code=x` to be detected, you need to add the Query String Append flag to the `RewriteRule`, as below:

```
RwriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [QSA,L]
```

This will append whatever query string is in the URI to the already existing `?$1`.

Comment: Thanks. But it didn't work.
Maybe codeigniter can't handle query string.

Comment: Try changing it to `^(.*)$ index.php/$1` or even just to `^ index.php`.

Comment: Still same.
It's not working either
RewriteRule ^ index.php/$1 [QSA,L]
or
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [QSA,L]

As I left the configuration as above, would you like to check how it work my site?
https://dashboard.come-to.tokyo/

Comment: This is a problem with your application, not with `.htaccess`. I'm not a CodeIgniter pro, and so not sure how to help you.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. OK, I'll ask someone else.